# ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone > integer)

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am using Rails 5.2 and passing a date parameter. To simplify my example, look at the below sql query, it is similar but simplified as it is too complex to be used with active record methods, so I need to run the raw sql..

```
sql = 'Select * FROM mytable WHERE created_at > #{@start_date_time}'
```

1) How do I sanitize the parameters as I pass them into a string or the execute command.

2) What format should my date be in?  I tried '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000' and '2018-01-01' and both error.

CODE:

```
sql =count_query(@start_date_time, sender_type, sender_id)
records_array = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

ERROR

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: 
ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone > integer)

LINE 11: WHERE created_at > 2018-01-01
```

Comment: I don't know enough about rails to tell you how to fix the issue, but the error is caused due to a lack of quoting.  It is trying to compare 2016 (2018 - 1 - 1) to created_at.

Answer (score 7):

WHERE created_at > '2018-01-01' should work